# Using automapper to map a child property to same model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper, change-tracking

**The problem**

I have a domain model that has a revisioning system build in to it. In concept it looks like this:

```
Model -> ModelDetails
```

The Model holds all the relations to other objects and has an `ICollection` of the `ModelDetails`. It also has a `details` property that shows the latest version. Until now I've mapped everything by manual coding to the viewmodels. Those are basically a combination of the `Model` and the `ModelDetails` (details property) object. The problem lies in defining that the mapping of the viewmodel come's both from the `Model` as the `Details` property (`ModelDetails` model).

With the example shown below I can make it with by using an extra call, but then I would need to place that call on every conversion place instead of just one mapping call. Another complexity is that because the relation are being mapped, I can't handle the revisioning of the relations atm.

**The domain models**

```
public class Model : RevisionBasedModel<Revisions.ModelDetails>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ModelTwo> RelationExample { get; set; } 
             = new HashSet<ModelTwo>();
}

public abstract class RevisionBasedModel<TRevision> : IRevisionBasedModel<TRevision> 
{
    public TRevision Details
    {
        get { return Revisions.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp).First();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<TRevision> Revisions { get; set; } 
            = new HashSet<TRevision>();
}

public class ModelDetails {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

**The viewmodel**

```
public class ModelVM {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RevisionId { get; set; }
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ModelTwoVM> RelationExample { get; set; }
            = new HashSet<ModelTwoVM>
}
```

**Current mapping configuration**

```
CreateMap<Model, ModelVM>()
    .ForMember(x => x.RelationExample, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.RelationExample));
CreateMap<ModelDetails, ModelVM>()
    .ForMember(x => x.RevisionId, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Id));

CreateMap<ModelTwo, ModelTwoVM>();
CreateMap<ModelTwoDetails, ModelTwoVM>()
    .ForMember(x => x.RevisionId, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.Id));
```

**Current conversion**

```
var viewModel = this._mapper.Map<Model, ModelVM>(model);
viewModel = this._mapper.Map<ModelDetails, ModelVM>(model.Details, viewModel);
```

---

**UPDATE 24-01-2017 19:26**

In the comments, the suggestion was made for a possible 'crude' way, by using a Custom type converter. I was able to make the revision part working, but because the default mapping is overwritten I lose my relation mapping.

```
public class RevisionConverter<TModel, TRevision, TViewModel> : ITypeConverter<TModel, TViewModel>
    where TModel : IRevisionBasedModel<int, TRevision>
{
    public TViewModel Convert(TModel source, TViewModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return context.Mapper.Map<TRevision, TViewModel>(source.Details, destination);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoMapper Map Child Property that also has a map defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944577/automapper-map-child-property-that-also-has-a-map-defined)

Comment: It isn't the same. That example has one input model and two output. I have two input and one output.

Comment: OK, thought it might be helpful.

Comment: I've tried something like that, but I couldn't figure it out. I'm still trying other things. Will add my findings later on

Comment: The blunt approach would be to use a [custom Type Converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters)

Comment: The problem with the custom type converter is that, if I specify the converter the normal mapping will disappear. If I would try to map it again in the converter I would get an access violation. I've added the converter in the post